# Разбить файл на строки

Tags: php, строки

Как разбить строку которая заканчивается разрывом строки. Пробовал `explode('\n', $str)` - не получилось.

Comment: поменяйть \n на \r\n

Comment: Не работает,получилось подставить PHP_EOL

Comment: Может дело в том что нужно \n заключать в двойные кавычки? - "\n"

Answer (score 1):

> Пробовал `explode('\n', $str)`

Для таких случаев лучше использовать [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php). Указывая `"/\n/"`, регулярка сама определит, в зависимости от ОС, какую последовательность символов считать признаком новой строки.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, `"\n"` (и другие подобные символы) должны заключаться в двойные кавычки, иначе `php` "видит" не перевод строки, а два символа: `"\"` и букву `"n"`.

Во вторых, в разные операционных системах символы перевода строки могут отличаться: В Windows - `"\r\n"`, в Unix'овых - `"\n"` и т.д.; поэтому лучше использовать константу `PHP_EOL`.

В третьих, если Вам нужно получить в виде массива именно файл, то есть [замечательная функция `file()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php)

Comment: 1) Двойные кавычки активируют интерполяцию строк. Звучит умнее :) 2) `\n` есть и там, и там. Проблема в первом пункте.